# Using Scrapy not able fetch child xpath from parent div

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, python-3.6

While trying to fetch the child div inside a div[there are 28 parent divs], the xpath is not iterating.

Able to get each parent div

```
product_divs=scrap_product_detail_response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'s-expand-height s-include-content-margin s-border-bottom')]")
print(len(product_divs))
for product_div in product_divs:
    img_urls=product_div.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal')]//text()").extract()
    print(img_urls)
```

Currently, the output is getting as 
1.jpg
1.jpg
1.jpg

Expected:
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
product_divs=scrap_product_detail_response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'s-expand-height s-include-content-margin s-border-bottom')]")
print(len(product_divs))
for product_div in product_divs:
    img_urls=product_div.xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal')]//text()").extract()
    print(img_urls)
```

You've written all the things correct but you left that (dot) of relative xpath